# Why am I getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error?

Tags: sql, group-by

Just a disclaimer, I'm very new to SQL... so please go easy on me. This is the script I have so far, and for the most part it's working, I'm just having a problem trying to only get the most recent DTTM record. What's wrong with my group by expression?

```
select
    i.item_name,
    i.description,
    MAX(w.LAST_UPDATED_DTTM)as MOST_RECENT_DTTM,
    w.last_updated_source,
    w.tc_lpn_id,
    lh1.dsp_locn as from_locn,
    l.dsp_locn,
    lh2.dsp_locn as dest_locn,
    lp.inventory_lock_code
    
from wm_inventory W

left join Locn_hdr l
on w.location_id = L.locn_id

left join item_cbo i
on w.item_id = i.item_id

left join lpn_lock lp
on lp.tc_lpn_id = w.tc_lpn_id

left join task_dtl td
on td.cntr_nbr = w.tc_lpn_id

left join locn_hdr lh2
on td.dest_locn_id = lh2.locn_id

left join locn_hdr lh1
on td.PULL_LOCN_ID = lh1.locn_id


where i.color_desc = '00607'
and l.DSP_LOCN like '%SRT-0%'
and w.tc_lpn_id not like '%J%'

group by i.item_name, i.description, w.last_updated_source, w.tc_lpn_id, l.dsp_locn, lp.inventory_lock_code, lh1.dsp_locn, lh2.dsp_locn
order by w.last_updated_dttm asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

To order by a column that's aggregated, you have to specify the aggregation:

```
order by MAX(w.last_updated_dttm) asc
```

Some implementations (including Oracle, you gave an Oracle error code) allow you to order by the aggregated column's alias:

```
order by MOST_RECENT_DTTM asc
```